# Express middleware not having an effect

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
var port = Number(process.env.PORT || 5000);

app.get('/test/:id', function(req, res) {
    res.send(req.params);
});

app.listen(port);
console.log("Listening on port " + port);
```

When I hit `http://localhost:5000/test/12345` in my browser, I see:

```
[]
```

But I'm expecting to see the populated req.params object with `id: 12345`.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Checked and saw that req.params is actually an associative array, which is almost similar to object but not quite. Not sure why express defined it as such. The only benefit it gets is the added length property for an array. And res.send will try to JSON.stringify your output, which in turn will see that it's an array and only take care of indexes which are numeric. Hence the empty [] as return value.

You can validate this by doing -

```
var myParams = {};

Object.keys(req.params).forEach(function(key){
    myParams[key] = req.params[key];
});

res.send(myParams);
```

You can also see that JSON.stringify only cares about numeric index by defining your route as such -

```
app.get('/test/:0', function(req, res) {
    res.send(req.params);
});
```

Comment: Its an associative array because you can get positional as well as named params.  The length property will not be what you're implying; its only going to be the count of positional params.

Comment: When will you need positional params in this case? I have always seen named parameters for get requests.

Comment: I believe a route using `*` will contain positional param(s) i.e. `/test/*`.

Answer (score 1):

The response object will be named after your `id`. If you check it in your browser's traffic you can see a file called `12345`. Though you can check that your server gets the id by logging it on the server side.

```
 app.get('/test/:id', function(req, res) {
      console.log(req.params);
      res.send(req.params);
 });
```

If you want to pass variables to a view you might want to use the `res.render(...)` function where you can pass in arguments.

To get the `123451` send the `res.send(req.params.id);`.

Comment: It is not sending as file... res.sendfile() is provided for that.

Comment: It names the response object after the id. I'll correct it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are not getting anything using `res.send(req.params)` is because `req.params` is an instance of `Array` and default mechanism tries to covet an array into string which is giving you `[]`.

What you could do to see all params is as follows:

```
app.get('/test/:id', function(req, res) {
    res.send(require('util').inspect(req.params));
});
```

That will give you output like (using this URL `http://localhost:5000/test/12345`):

```
[ id: '12345' ]
```

That approach will also work with routes having more parameters e.g. the following code snippet and that request `http://localhost:5000/test/name/234`

```
app.get('/test/:name/:id', function(req, res) {
    res.send(require('util').inspect(req.params));
});
```

will give you:

```
[ name: 'name', id: '234' ]
```

Alternatively, if you would like to get JSON formatted output of a JavaScript object, you can use `res.json`. But note that `json` will also generate `[]` if you perform `res.json(req.params)` as it will render `req.params` array in a standard way.

I hope that will help.

---

**Note** that as of **9th April 2014** ([Express version **4.0.0**](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/History.md#400--2014-04-09)) `req.params` is an object instead of an array so you should not have similar issues with v4.0.0 and your code should work as expected.

```
app.get('/test/:id', function(req, res) {
    res.send(req.params);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't your middleware.  Neither bodyParser nor cookieParser provide the named url parameter parsing.  That being said, your code looks correct to me.  Are you absolutely certain you restarted your node server after making the code change?

Comment: Express provides that with its router.

Comment: A couple users above caught the real problem - the serialization of an array is different from that of an object and the properties aren't being sent.  Either pull them off directly (req.params.id)  or convert to an object.